# formal Proof of an inequality

Tags: formal-proofs

In trying  to prove , $a\leq b\wedge b\leq c\Longrightarrow a\leq c$ I come up with the following:

Proof:
(intuitively)

case 1:  $a<b\wedge b<c\Longrightarrow a<c\Longrightarrow a\leq c$

case 2: $a<b\wedge b=c\Longrightarrow a<c\Longrightarrow a\leq c$

case 3: $a=b\wedge b<c\Longrightarrow a<c\Longrightarrow a\leq c$

case 4 : $ a=b\wedge b=c\Longrightarrow a=c\Longrightarrow a\leq c$

My question is :

What  is the corresponding formal proof of the above proof within a natural deduction system ??

Comment: is transitivity a law of logic ??

Comment: On base of transitivity of $<$ you proved transitivity of $\leq$. What I am missing in your proof is the statement that $<$ is indeed a transitive relation. If your excuse for that is that $<$ is usually the notation of a transitive relation then you are implicitly saying that a proof is not needed: also $\leq$ is usually the notation of a transitive (and also reflexive) relation.

Comment: (would just like to point out a format mistake in 'l' instead of 'L' for the 'implies' arrow in case 4)

Comment: @user149368 Not sure what you're after - could you clarify? Are you after laws in logic as in the 3 laws (identity, non-contradiction, excluded middle)? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_thought#The_law_of_identity

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to prove the transitivity of $≤$.

For the first implication you assumed the transitivity of $<$ in case 1. In cases 2, 3 and 4, you used the definition of equality.

For the final implication in each case, you used the definition of $≤$ which is $≤ \,\,\, := \,\,\, (< \lor =$).

Comment: Are, transitivity of < ,definition of equality, definition of less or equal, laws of logic??

Comment: @user149368 No they're not. Was a little unsure on what you were looking for initially. Include the `logic` tag or similar if you're after that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formal proof, using fairly standard logical inference rules

1. $\forall x \forall y \forall z \ ((x < y \land y < z) \rightarrow x < z)$ (Axiom)
2. $\forall x \forall y \ (x \le y \leftrightarrow (x < y \lor x = y))$ (Axiom)
3. $a \le b \land b \le c$ (Assumption)
4. $a \le b$ ($\land $ Elim, 4)
5. $b \le c$ ($\land $ Elim, 4)
6. $a \le b \leftrightarrow (a < b \lor a = b)$ ($\forall$ Elim, 2)
7. $a < b \lor a = b$ ($\leftrightarrow$ Elim, 4,7)
8. $b \le c \leftrightarrow (b < c \lor b = c)$ ($\forall$ Elim, 2)
9. $b < c \lor b = c$ ($\leftrightarrow$ Elim, 5,8)
10. $a \le c \leftrightarrow (a < c \lor a = c)$ ($\forall$ Elim, 2)

(and now you do cases. First on 7: Case 1:)

11. $a < b$ (Assumption)

(And now cases on 9: Case 1A: (this corresponds to your case 1))

12. $b < c$ (Assumption)
13. $a < b \land b < c$ ($\land$ Intro, 11,12)
14. $(a < b \land b < c) \rightarrow a < c$ ($\forall$ Elim, 1)
15. $a < c$ ($\rightarrow$ Elim,13, 14)
16. $a < c \lor a = c$ ($\lor$ Intro, 15)
17. $a \le c$ ($\leftrightarrow$ Elim, 10,16)

(that completed Case 1A, Now do Case 1B (corresponding to your case 2))

18. $b = c$ (Assumption)
19. $a < c$ ($=$ Elim, 11,18)
20. $a < c \lor a = c$ ($\lor$ Intro, 19)
21. $a \le c$ ($\leftrightarrow$ Elim, 10,20)

(and that completes 1B. Wrap up with:)

22. $a \le c$ ($\lor$ Elim, 9,12-17,18-21)

(now start Case 2:)

23. $a = b$ (Assumption)

(This one splits as well. Case 2A: (your case 3)

24. $b < c$ (Assumption)
25. $a < c$ ($=$ Elim, 23,24)
26. $a < c \lor a = c$ ($\lor$ Intro, 25)
27. $a \le c$ ($\leftrightarrow$ Elim, 10,26)

(finally, Case 2B (your case 4):)

28. $b=c$ (Assumption)
29. $a= c$ ($=$ Elim, 23, 28)
30. $a < c \lor a = c$ ($\lor$ Intro, 29)
31. $a \le c$ ($\leftrightarrow$ Elim, 10,30)

(wrap up Case 2 with:)

32. $a \le c$ ($\lor$ Elim, 9,24-27,28-31)

(and now wrap us Case 1 and 2):

33. $a \le c$ ($\lor$ Elim, 7,11-22,23-32)

Comment: Surely a formal proof  without showing the laws of logic taking place in the proof is not a formal proof

Comment: @user149368 True, but like I said, there many different formal proof systems, each with their own set of inference rules. So, if you want an answer to your question, you will have to tell me what formal proof system you are working with. As long as you don't this 'pseudo formal proof' is the best I can do. I can't read your mind!

Comment: I did write in my OP ,within a natural deduction system

Comment: Let me also give you the appropriate axioms and definitions.1) the trichotomy law 2) transitive law < 3) addition law of < 4) multiplication law of < and 5) the definition of the relation  les or equal

Comment: @user149368 There are still a lot of different natural deduction systems.  Also, I can guess what the trichotomy and transitivity law for < are, but I am not too sure what you mean by the addition and multiplication laws for < (though I doubt you need those for this proof ...). The definition of less than or equal is of course crucial for this proof, What is the axiom for that?  Is that the same as what I had in my post, i.e. $\forall x \forall y (x \le y \leftrightarrow (x < y \lor x = y))$?

Comment: the definition is the same with the one you had in your post. The axioms to back up this definition are those of equality and <

Comment: Addition law or axiom for < is: a<b => a+c<b+c.And multiplication law for < is: for 0<c ,then a<b implies ac<bc

Comment: @user149368  OK, I updated the proof with your axioms. Having a transitivity axiom for $<$ made that a good bit simpler.  I also added in some more lines dealing with the pure logic. Again, there are different formal proof systems, so this ma not follow the format of the one you work with, but this is a legitimate formal proof for the 'Fitch' system I usually work with: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitch_notation

Comment: lines 11,12,18,23,24,28 are not justified and in a formal proof no line of the proof is unjustified

Comment: @user149368 OK, let me fix that! ... All done! :)

Comment: please explaine the law: (v Elim 9,12-17,18-21)

Comment: @user149368 9 says that either $b<c$ or $b=c$. So, we'll explore those two cases. first, on line 12 we assume $b<c$, and after some further inferences, we find that that assumption leads to $a<c$ on line 17. Then we assume the other possibility: $b=c$ by assuming that on line 18. And again, after some further inferences, we find $a<c$. So, since either one of $b<c$ or $b=c$ is true (line 12), and since the assumption of either one leads to $a<c$ (as lines 12 through 17 and lines 18 through 21 show respectively), we can conclude $a<c$. This pattern of reasoning is called Proof by Cases. 1/2

Comment: @user149368 And the Proof by Cases kind of reasoning (which you did yourself when you considered 4 cases in your proof) is formalized by $\lor Elim$. Note that the assumptions of $b<c$ and $b=c$ were 'discharged' at that point, so that the pnly assumptions left at the very end are just the very axioms from the beginning.

Comment: Proof by cases : [(PvQ)&(P=>R)&(Q=>R)]=> R you are missing the (P=>R),(Q=>R) parts

Comment: In a duductive proof the words "true", "false" are of no importance

Comment: @user149368 Again, it all depends on what specific formal proof system you are using. For the one I used here, you don't need to get the explicit conditionals; ypu just need to that the assumption of P leads to R, and that the assumption of Q leads to R.

Comment: @user149368 I am not following you last comment about 'true' and 'false' ... Is that a question?